# Adding two axios get requests in React and Wordpress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, axios

So, I'm trying to have Wordpress as a backend, and React as front end. 
On my homepage, I want to display a column of pages and posts.
 When I click on the page and post links, it would take me to the single page or post.

I can only do one axios request at a time, it seems if I add another get request with axios, it throws "post.title is undefined. "

```
My Pages.js

import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";



 class Pages extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            page: {},
        };
        this.createMarkup = this.createMarkup.bind();
    }

componentDidMount() {
  const slug = this.props.match.params.slug;

    axios
    .get(`http://localhost:8888/WP_Weact/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?slug=${slug}`)
    .then(page => {
        this.setState({
            page: page.data[0]
        });
    });
}    

createMarkup(html) {
    return { __html: html };
}


    render() {
        let build;

        if(this.state.page.title) {
            build = (
            <div>
          <h1>{this.state.page.title.rendered}</h1>
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup( this.state.page.content.rendered )} />
        </div>
            );
        } else {
            build = <div/>;
        }
        return build;      

    }
}

export default Pages;
```

```
My Post.js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";



 class PostView extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            post: {},
        };
        this.createMarkup = this.createMarkup.bind();
    }

componentDidMount() {
  const slug = this.props.match.params.slug;

    axios
    .get(`http://localhost:8888/WP_Weact/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=${slug}`)
    .then(post => {
        this.setState({
            post: post.data[0]
        });
    });
}    

createMarkup(html) {
    return { __html: html };
}


    render() {
        let build;

        if(this.state.post.title) {
            build = (
            <div>
          <h1>{this.state.post.title.rendered}</h1>
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup( this.state.post.content.rendered )} />
        </div>
            );
        } else {
            build = <div/>;
        }
        return build;      

    }
}




export default PostView;
```

```
app.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Header from "./components/header";
import PostList from "./components/PostList";
//import PostView from "./components/PostView";
import Posts from "./components/Posts";
import Pages from "./components/Pages";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';


const App = () => (
  <Router>
  <div>
    <Header />
    <section className="section container content">
    <Route exact path="/" component={PostList} /> 
    <Route path="/:slug" component={Posts} />
    <Route path="/:slug" component={Pages} />



    </section>
  </div>
  </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Comment: what line is the error pointing to?

Comment: If I click on Post.js or Page.js, it will point to either one changing from "TypeError: this.state.post is undefined"  or "TypeError: this.state.page is undefined"

However. if I only use Page.js or Post.js it will work, not both of them together if that makes any sense.

Comment: can you console.log the state of each component and then try clicking on the other one and see if it alters the other state?

Comment: Just checked and it does. So, on Page, it says this.state.post is undefined and vise versa, along with quite a few others errors

Comment: Try to simplify your problem and ask again. Your axios get queries are the same on the my_pages.js and my_post.js and this doesn't have sense